# What string type(s) should my library support?

Tags: c++, string

I’m writing a pretty-printing combinator library in C++17, which involves representing documents as tree structures with client-provided strings in the leaves. What kinds of string type(s) should clients of my library be allowed to provide? Right now I have it templated like so:

```
template<
        class CharT,
        class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>,
        class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
>
class basic_document
{
public:
    using text_type = std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>;
    using text_view_type = std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>;
    …
};
```

So this code will work with `std::string`, `std::wstring`, or any other instance of `std::basic_string<CharT>`. But I’m wondering whether that is either too much or too little flexibility, because I don't know what kinds of strings people use, or how difficult conversions are. Is it reasonable to fix it to a UTF-8 `std::string`, or conversely, should I support non-`std` string classes somehow?

Comment: Do you need `CharT`, `Traits`, and `Allocator`, else you might use `template <typename String> class basic_document;`

Comment: On input convert to UTF-8 on output convert to whatever is required.  This simplifies your storage format to just UTF-8.  `std::string` is a reasonable container for UTF-8, however if you have to do any character processing you will probably need to use a Unicode library.

Comment: @Jarod42: No, I might not need those. `template <typename String> class basic_document` might be fine.

Comment: Keyword "ducktyping"...

Comment: @RichardCritten: Yes, I think utf8everywhere.org might be right. And yeah, my next question will involve Unicode processing.

Comment: UTF8 is best for encoding ready text, however UTF32 is better at processing it.

Comment: Try to support `char*`

Comment: @Mikhail: Is supporting [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) sufficient support for `char*`?

Comment: @rieux No, but you can get the length from some O(n) count.

Comment: @rieux You need support for `const char*` also